# Class attributes always set as strings?

Tags: php, string, class, static, attributes

First time I noticed this today whilst using a PHP class static attribute $limit as a query limit parameter for a raw prepared statement as in

```
/**
 * @var int
 */
private static $limit = 100;

// ....

        $query = <<<EOT
SELECT id FROM table t WHERE t.id > 0 LIMIT ? EOT;

$recs = \DB::select($query, [self::$limit]);
```

So the above query throws an error which upon examination seemed to me to stem from the fact that the query builder took it for a string. If I change the select statement to be as follows it all runs as expected

```
$mcdrs = \DB::select($query, [(int)self::$limit]);
```

So, whilst this is not a problem per se, I am just curious as to whether is a known fact that class attributes in PHP are always set as strings.

I even changed the attribute declaration to

```
private static $limit = 99+1;
```

with the same results. Just to confirm, I performed the following "tests" and I can confirm that no matter what I do with the static var declaration they are all reported as strings. Haven't tried floating numbers though.

```
    if (is_string(self::$limit)) {
        die('string');
    } elseif (is_int(self::$limit)) {
        die('int');
    } else {
        die('something else...');
    }
```

I can confirm that the variable is of type string.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this as a test and could not replicate your findings.
**This is using PHP 7.3.19**

**/Class_test.php**

```
class Class_test {
    private static $limit = 100;
    private static $string = '100';

    public function index() {

        $this->check_my_type(self::$limit);
        $this->check_my_type(self::$string);
    }

    protected function check_my_type($value){
        if (is_string($value)) {
            echo('I am a string :'. $value);
            echo '<br>';
        }

        if (is_int($value)) {
            echo('I am an Integer :'.$value);
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

**/index.php**

```
<?php
// Enable FULL Error Reporting on the screen
// ONLY USE IN DEVELOPMENT
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include_once('./Class_test.php');

$test = new Class_test();
$test->index();
```

**Output is:**

```
I am an Integer :100
I am a string :100
```

Do you get the same results or is there something you haven't told us that I am missing here.